# Equivalent to `setx` in powershell

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

Windows has a powershell command called [`setx`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104(v=ws.11).aspx) which Creates or modifies environment variables in the user or system environment.

Does Ubuntu has a similar command, i.e. not by using `nano` or `vi`, just one line to add or update an environment variable system wide.

## Implemented Solution

One line to add/update

```
grep env_name /etc/environment && sed -i.bak 's/env_name=.*/env_name="env_value"/' /etc/environment || echo 'env_name="env_value"' >> /etc/environment
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this simply by declaring it as new in the command line or re-declaring it. For example, if you want to add `~/testfolder` to your path variable, you simply can enter it in your current terminal (this is just an example):

```
PATH="$HOME/testfolder:$PATH"
```

This will of course only change it for the time you have said terminal session open. Notice the `$` usage here, you leave it out for declaration, but if you want to display it you need to add `$` to expand its contents.

If you want to declare them more lasting and general you can add them into your `~/.bashrc` (only for you) file or in `/etc/bash.bashrc` (system wide) for example if you want them to be counting for only you or for all users. Another option is to add it to your `.profile` file (only for yourself) where it will be viable from the moment you log in. You can do this with `echo` for example if you're sure this variable is not set already or if you create new ones (only an example):

```
echo "variable=value" >> /path/filename
```

If you however want to edit a file outside your user directory which is the case when you want to edit `/etc/bash.bashrc` you need to use `sudo` and so you cant simply use a 'here document' since this would not work, instead use then a line like below:

```
echo "variable=value" | sudo tee -a /path/filename
```

If the variable however already exists you can change it with the `sed` command (also only an example):

```
sed -i.bak 's/variable=value/variable=new-value/' /path/filename
```

This will edit the variable in file but create a backup of it prior to the edit. If you change files outside your user directory with sed you need to use `sudo` in most cases so the line would be:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/variable=value/variable=new-value/' /path/filename
```

Removing a variable from a file can be done with `sed` as well, just leave the second part of the regex empty:

```
sed -i.bak 's/variable=value//' /path/filename
```

If your interested which environment variables are set you can use the `env` command to list them, `( set -o posix ; set ) | less` or `sh -c set`. All three give various amounts of output, with `( set -o posix ; set ) | less` giving back the most variables which are actually set.

Comment: Instead of `( set -o posix ; set )` it's simpler to say `sh -c set`. This will work even if `sh` is a symlink to `bash` (which isn't normally on modern Ubuntu versions).

Comment: @ruslan `sh -c set` is not showing really all environment variables set on the system. However i will include it as a third way to show some of them.

Comment: Actually `sh -c set` shows all _environment_ variables. It just doesn't show  _shell_ variables of the calling shell, but these are never inherited by a process you run from that shell, unless you `export` them.

Comment: Is there _ever_ a valid reason to edit `/etc/environment`? Seems like that's a shortcut to confusion.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Thank you, wasn't sure about that, it is still a viable place to edit variables in, but I took it out for the sake of not causing confusion.

Comment: If you want to set variables for every user, you'd generally put something in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d`. If you want to set a variable for the current user, use `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile` (though I can never remember exactly which one). I think `/etc/environment` affects _everything_ (including system scripts), and that's probably a _really_ bad idea.

Answer (score 12):

There is no direct equivalent of `setx /m`, but there are ways to accomplish what `setx /m` does.

`setx /m` puts `variable=value` in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. Non-/m (i.e. per-user) `setx` simply puts the `variable=value` in `HKCU\Environment`.

You specifically asked for 'system wide'. For that, you would add the variable-value pair to either `/etc/environment` OR to `/etc/profile.d/<yourfile>`. The former is evaluated by pam, while the latter is evaluated by `/bin/sh`. Thus,  in `/etc/profile.d/<yourfile>`, you would add `variable=value; export variable`. (bash also allows `export variable=value`). For `/etc/environment` you would add `variable=value`.

The per-user equivalents are `~/.pam_environment` and `~/.profile`.

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 7):

You can export environment variables on command line, but it won't affect the effective environment in already started processes, only in the current process and its subprocesses. So in practice you often need to relogin when changing environment variables.