# Setting CDPATH environment variable

Tags: environment, cd-command

"export CDPATH=/usr", like this I want to manipulate CDPATH environment variable. Then I can't be sure it is the same as before when I put "export CDPATH=." on the command line and enter. So, I want to know where this CDPATH variable goes. Where do I confirm the changes of variable in a file?? Furthermore, where are all the environment variables go in Ubuntu?? Are they go to the all the same file or all different files? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/981123/setx-equivalent-in-ubuntu/981129#981129 ?

Answer (score 3):

The environment variable $CDPATH sets a path which tells the `cd` command where to search for its destination directories.

For example if you set `CDPATH=$HOME`, you can cd to any subdirectory of $HOME from wherever you are. Setting `CDPATH=.` doesn't make much sense as the current directory is always considered the starting point for cd. If you always want a certain value for $CDPATH you should set it in any of the files bash reads when it starts : `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, etc. Take a look at the many questions as to where define $PATH.